# isomorphism of the group by plus one of its elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say there's a group **G=(S,+)**, and **a** is a certain element of it. Then I can get a new group **G'** by applying a projection **f(g)=g+a** to every element in **G**.

Will the new group **G'** necessarily be isomorphic to **G**? If it's not, what condition should the original group **G** satisfy?

Comment: Automorphism is a bijective homomorphism from a group to itself, so the new group is not an "automorphism". You ate not telling us what the operation on $G'$ is, but if it is obtained by transport of structure, then necessarily the result is isomorphic to the original.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I've revised it. Sorry for my ignorance in Math terms.

Comment: Why do you think $G'$ is a new group? I don't see how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether $G'$ will be *isomorphic* to $G$, the answer is yes, since $a\in G$. We can prove this, too. Define a map $\varphi: G\to G'$ by $\varphi(g) = f(g)-a = g+a-a = g$. Then $\varphi$ is the identity map, and you can easily verify that this is an isomorphism.

Another way to check is that $G'$ has the same operation $+$ as $G$, so all we need to check is set inclusion. Clearly for all $g\in G$, $g = (g-a)+a \in G'$ so $G\subseteq G'$. Also, for all $g' \in G'$, we have $g' = f(g) = g+a$ for some $g\in G$, but $g+a\in G$ so $g'\in G$. Thus $G'\subseteq G$ and hence $G=G'$. We have two groups which have the same set and binary operation. They are the same group, and hence they are trivially isomorphic.